# Zurb Foundation Equalizer

Tags: javascript, zurb-foundation

I'm trying to use this Foundation plugin: http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/equalizer.html

This is my code:

```
<div class="row" data-equalizer>
    <div class="large-4 medium-6 small-12 columns" data-equalizer-watch>
        {some content}
    </div>
    <div class="large-4 medium-6 small-12 columns" data-equalizer-watch>
        {some content}
    </div>
    <div class="large-4 medium-6 small-12 columns" data-equalizer-watch>
        {some content}
    </div>
</div>
```

I've then added before the end of my body the following scripts:

```
<script src="js/foundation.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/foundation/foundation.reveal.js"></script>
<script src="js/foundation/foundation.datepicker.js"></script>
<script src="js/foundation/foundation.dropdown.js"></script>
<script src="js/foundation/foundation.equalizer.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).foundation();
</script>
</body>
```

The problem is just that Equalizer is not working.

All the .js are loaded correctly (no 404 errors), and Javascript Console is not throwing any kind of error.
Everything seems to be just fine to me, where am I wrong?
Thanks guys.

Comment: I don't see anything immediately wrong. Is this just an html/css/js site, or is this site built into a CMS that may be causing some cache issues?

Comment: I've copied the code in a page without anything else than this. It's not working.

Comment: Your html is fine as you can see here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Ffxly

Comment: It may be that you're including foundation.min.js which has foundation.equalizer.js inside of it. So you're including the equalizer functions twice by adding the plugins individually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either load each plugin individually, or include foundation.min.js, which automatically loads the Foundation Core and all JavaScript plugins.

```
<script src="/js/foundation.min.js"></script>

<!-- or individually -->

<script src="/js/foundation.js"></script>
<script src="/js/foundation.alert.js"></script>
<!-- ... -->
<script src="/js/foundation.dropdown.js"></script>
<script src="/js/foundation.tab.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yeah, actually this was the problem.
Thanks